# Why do Shinigami Captains always use their release command?

Tags: bleach

During the [battle between Renji Abarai and Byakuya Kuchki](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Renji_Abarai_vs._Byakuya_Kuchiki) which takes place soon after Renji learned Bankai, Byakuya indicates that being able to release ones Shikai without using the release command indicates that a Shinigami has learned Bankai.

As shortcuts go, this seems like a useful one (especially for those with longer release commands). This is the only time I recall seeing this ability though. Even the captains, who all know Bankai (except for Zaraki until the final arc), always use their release command.

I could accept that this ability is possible but not guaranteed except that the flashbacks of Renji at the academy indicate that things don't come to him as naturally as other Shinigami. He has skills but he had to work for them while others have natural abilities that they honed. The captains, on the other hand, are the most powerful Shinigami in existence. It seems like at least one of them would use this ability on a regular basis. So why don't they? Is it just habit?

Looking for in universe answers here. I get that, at the beginning of the series, the creators probably didn't want a multitude of lengthy flashbacks just to explain what was about to happen in a relatively short fight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Names and words have power

This principle is perhaps most clearly demonstrated by Yumichika, who intentionally hides the true nature and power of his weapon by calling it by a name it hates.  When he uses its true name, it is a vastly different beast.

And learning your sword's name also amplifies its powers.  Ichigo's power increases when he learns his sword's name, as does Zaraki's.  Much of this seems explicable as simply increasing the harmony between them (this is one of Zangetsu's reasons for why Zaraki wasn't nearly as powerful as he could be in his first fight with Ichigo), but nevertheless the concept seems to be relevant.  Much as you'd feel you had a closer, more productive relationship to someone if they knew your name versus if they didn't.

Additionally, while training Ichigo Urahara comments that an ability becomes more powerful when you know and use its name.  This is sort of a self-enforcing trope in manga and anime: to keep the reader/viewer in the know it is necessary that attack names be said out loud, despite obvious tactical disadvantages to doing so, and several works use the rationale that the power is amplified when the correct name is used. Ichigo can use Getsuga Tenshou without having to say the name, but it's much more powerful when he says the name. Byakuya's comments to Renji about a command-free release reflects the idea that in order to release that level of power without the name you must already be capable of a much greater release of power: a bankai.

A similar mechanic is used with kidou: it is possible to cast them without the lengthy incantations, but the power is much greater if you use them.  Thus we know that when someone uses a kidou with no incantation to devastating effect then they must be extremely potent and proficient. Byakuya uses several mid-level kidou (about level 60 or so) without incantations, reflecting his all-around excellency, and Aizen uses top-tier kidou without them to one-shot other Captains.